# Is it possible to run program in python with additional HTTP server in infinite loop?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to run program in infinite loop which handles GPIO in raspberry PI and gets requests in infinite loop (as HTTP server). Is it possible? I tried Flask framework, but infinite loop waits for requests and then my program is executed.

Comment: Why infinite loop?

Comment: Because I want to handle requests and also do something with my hardware.

Comment: I don't believe an infinite loop is actually what you're looking for - you would  need to program a system that sits idle until a command or parameter is passed to it to perform some function. Alternatively if its a server-like system, continue calling a search for incoming data to perform some service. Neither of these are actual "infinite loops".

Comment: Do you have a choice to use another platform or Python is the only choice ? I would suggest you to go for NodeJS , it will make your life and this task easier

Answer (score 0):

If I were to face with a problem like this right now, I wold do this:

1) First I'd try figuring out if I can use the event loop of the web framework to execute the code communicating with raspberry-pi asynchronously (i.e. inside of the event handlers).

2) If I failed to find a web framework extensible enough to do what I need or if it turned out that the raspberry-pi part can't be done asynchronously (e.g. it is taking to long to execute), I would figure out what is the difference between threads and processes in python, which of the two can I use in my specific situation and what tools can help me with that.

This answer is as specific as the question (at the time of writting).